# The input data is not a complete block when reading stream of bytes in POST data

Tags: c#, encryption, aes, encryption-symmetric, ecb

I have a web service where I am reading a stream of data from a POST request. But when I read it from the  Request.InputStream, it gives me error saying "**The input data is not a complete block**."

However, when I try to read it from a file that was sent to me by my colleague,  it works even though both contain the same data.

Following is the data :

> 3721 b1cc 1759 3067 f993 7c3d bda9 4f04 547c ea1b 3974 2bd1 f213 74a5
>   2036 7927 e679 bab5 7bbc 3fbf 6a30 85e9 38a8 b877 4855 37e5 5751 f1da
>   ca75 578e 7d32 ce07 9e47 9ad7 34fe b70a 331d 7c4a a5e7 12b1 594a d329
>   74bb 5d24 2088 738a 9978 cecc 9a04 8686 c451 086b cd44 5e2b cb2b 98db
>   d9ec 73ef 9433 c9f3 185c 3d8e a610 6f30 642c 83e0 3ce4 4804 74aa 22cf
>   6378 d49c fd73 a6e9 d0ab 53cd 3cb5 f4da a05f 93c9 e4ae 6a53 91ee aa0d
>   72d7 3ab9 7100 302c

The file sent by my colleague is created from a lisp program and that file is successfully decrypted using my code below. But when I read the data above as the input stream in Request and try to decrypt it, it throws the error.

```
           System.IO.Stream str; String strmContents;
           Int32 strLen, strRead;

           // read the data
           str = Request.InputStream;
           strLen = Convert.ToInt32(str.Length);
           byte[] strArray = new byte[strLen];
           strRead = str.Read(strArr, 0, strLen);
           strArray.ToArray();

// This works
byte[] data2 = File.ReadAllBytes("file.data").ToArray();
byte[] dec = decryptMessage(data2);

// This throws error
contents = decryptMessage(strArray);

public string decryptMessage(byte[] data)
{         
    byte[] decryptedBytes = Decrypt(data, key);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedBytes);
}

public byte[] encryptMessage(string plainText)
{
    byte[] encryptedBytes = Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText), key);             
    return encryptedBytes;
}

public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] data, byte[] key)
{
    using (AesCryptoServiceProvider csp = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        csp.KeySize = 128;
        csp.BlockSize = 128;
        csp.Key = key;
        csp.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
        csp.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        ICryptoTransform encrypter = csp.CreateEncryptor();
        return encrypter.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
}

private static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] data, byte[] key)
{
    using (AesCryptoServiceProvider csp = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        csp.KeySize = 128;
        csp.BlockSize = 128;
        csp.Key = key;
        csp.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
        csp.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        ICryptoTransform decrypter = csp.CreateDecryptor();
        return decrypter.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you think I am doing it wrong.

Comment: Debug and see what value `strLen` has. And if the (first few) bytes look the same.

Comment: Also peculiar: should you not be reading the _response_.stream?

Comment: No I think its request.inputstream that I should be reading because thats where the parameters are.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was the wrong data input. We checked the content length and strewn as well, but then the device programmer realized that he had been sending me faulty encrypted data files so it wasn't working.

Also, to preserve the format of data, we had to use Request.BinaryRead() instead of Request.inputStream.

Otherwise, code works. Thank you all!!